# error code elifecycle error erno 1

Tags: npm

Пробовал заново копировать проект , удалял node module,json lock[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код в текст поместите, пожалуйста. Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь. Не надо копий экрана.

Comment: Проблема была в доступе, не было прав администратора